# Switching from nautilus to nemo not working 18.04

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, nemo, gnome-session-fallback

I use gnome-session-flashback on Ubuntu 18.04. I much prefer the nemo filemanager compared to Nautilus. I downloaded it via `apt-get install nemo`

I then looked around online to find out how to make nemo the default. I've tried many such as these

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

I then restarted but while some portions worked such as pressing `Home` on the `Places` tab on the top menu. Things like other applications opening the filemanager to upload file or download file. Another is if you click a link to a drive on the desktop also opens nautilus instead of nemo. 
I'd just like to never use Nautilus. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The repo nemo doesn't auto start nemo-desktop, you should add it to do so. To see if that's your issue run the command `nemo-desktop` (- preferred to do as a run command, i.e alt+F2 if your session does that.., otherwise try via a terminal though it will exit when terminal is closed.

Answer (score 0):

### Update June 8, 2019

There is a tutorial on installing `nemo` in Ubuntu:

- [How to Install Nemo in Ubuntu Without Cinnamon Dependencies](https://www.linuxslaves.com/2017/07/how-to-install-nemo-in-ubuntu-unity.html)

First install `nemo`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo3
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nemo
```

Then set `nemo` as the preference over `nautilus`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

If you change your mind or find `nemo` lacking in some way:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
sudo apt remove nemo
```

---

### Original answer

There is currently a bug report filed on `exo-utils` [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=892010).

You can try this:

```
sudo apt install exo-utils
```

Then run:

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

then switch to **Utilities** tab and select File Manager you prefer.

Comment: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=892010

Comment: @Ferroao Thanks for pointing that out. I've provided an alternate method side stepping that bug report.